# lpr/cups to screen instead of printer (to see how page will look)

Tags: printing, cups, lpr

I'd like some way of knowing how my document is going to look when it gets printed with lpr without actually wasting paper and ink.

My specific problem is that I'm working with tabular text that should not be wrapped, but also shouldn't be wider than the page.

I have no way to know how many characters will fit horizontally on a portrait print via lpr, and when I read the man-pages on my machine (macbook - darwin), it doesn't appear to have any relevant information.

Ideally, I'd like to see a sample output (whether stdin, or printing to an image and opening via gui, whatever) that will show me how my document will look.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing [CUPS-PDF](http://cups-pdf.de/) will allow you to create a virtual printer which prints to PDF files. You can then use that printer with `lpr -P` to preview your output.